# Upgrade to Python 2.7.10: Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python-2.7, apache2, mod-wsgi

When I upgrade Python from 2.7.9 to 2.7.10 with anaconda, I get the following error in my apache2 log and my websites don't work any more.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=608): Target WSGI script '/www/wsgi_scripts/django_myproject.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/www/wsgi_scripts/django_myproject.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/wsgi_scripts/django_myproject.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
    import django.core.handlers.wsgi
  File "/Users/xnx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 6, in <module>
    from io import BytesIO
  File "/Users/xnx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xnx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /Users/xnx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I expect this is some kind of mismatch in package library versions, but does anyone know which one?

Comment: Did you try rebuilding/reinstalling mod_wsgi? If using a Python virtual environment, did you recreate the Python virtual environment after the Python upgrade? Upgrading Python can often cause existing Python virtual environments to stop working.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Graham. I did reinstall mod_wsgi using pip, but I get the same error unless I downgrade Python.

Comment: Are you saying you are running ``mod_wsgi-express`` or are you using system wide Apache? If system wide, how has system Apache setup to know where to pick up mod_wsgi.so from? Doing a ``pip install mod_wsgi`` doesn't install the mod_wsgi '.so' file into system Apache modules directory and that would have to be done as a separate step if system Apache had been set up to pull it from system Apache modules directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your `PYTHONPATH` if it's correct (you don't override it anywhere in your startup files).

Otherwise you may consider downgrading your Python from 2.7.10 to 2.7.9.

For example (as suggested in [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367#issuecomment-118670462)):

```
conda install python=2.7.9
```

or [when using Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31887686/55075) try:

```
brew switch python 2.7.9
```

as it could be some particular problem with 2.7.10.

Alternatively use Python 3.x instead.

Comment: Yup, that's what I had to do. I can't migrate everything to Python 3, though.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that this is a problem with Anaconda as I've just hit the same problem. I've reported an issue here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367

**update**:

The conda guys have now released a fixed virtualenv package that no longer has this problem.

Comment: Thanks - despite my earlier comment (now deleted) I haven't been able to resolve this by recompiling and reinstalling mod_wsgi, so I think you're right: a problem with Anaconda.