# Python on my Mac is a mess, help me uninstall what I don't need

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I'm unable to import numpy in Python 2.7 in the shell. I installed Python with `brew install`, then numpy with `sudo pip install`. I tried without `sudo` but I get a permission denied error. Anyway, I get this:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException

Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

In `/usr/local/bin/` I have the following:

```
pip
pip2
pip2.7
pip3
pip3.4
```

And:

```
python
python-config
python2
python2-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
python3
python3-config
python3.4
python3.4-config
python3.4m
python3.4m-config
pythonw
pythonw2
pythonw2.7
```

The output of `which python` is `/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: can you post the output of "which python"

Comment: Thanks for the attention, Mitchell:`/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: See: [Homebrew upgrade to Python 2.7.10 breaks powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1384), it's for powerline, but some of the info there may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for workaround, try downgrading your Python to 2.7.9 like:

```
brew switch python 2.7.9
```

by overriding the existing one, as it seems there is some particular problem with 2.7.10. Then re-link it again (if required).

Also make sure your `PYTHONPATH` is correct (you don't override it anywhere in your startup files).

Comment: THANKS! Before trying the downgraded version I checked the PYTHONPATH and that's where the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

That output is normal. Have you tried running `brew install openssl` followed by `brew link --force openssl` and then `brew install python`. The following thread helps describe the issue https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40516

Comment: thanks for reassuring me that the output is normal! I tried that solution, but it didn't work. Usually I use 3.4, and it's working great, as a workaround for when I use 2.7, could I simply create a virtual environment? This wouldn't fix the original issue, but I'd have a clean version of 2.7?

Comment: Yes that's how I use python 3.4 on my system :)